# iTextSharp - How to convert Document to byte[]

Tags: c#, pdf, stream, itext

I need to attach a pdf I created in memory to an email. Attachments can take a stream. So I believe I need to convert a iTextSharp Document object to stream. How can I do that?
I tried serializing the Document object to a stream but it is not "marked as serializable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [iText.pdf.PdfWriter](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch01.html#step2). There are methods that take a stream.

Here's a sample for streaming in ASP.NET- [link text](http://alandennis.blogspot.com/2005/07/streaming-pdf-using-itextsharp-and.html)

Answer (score 24):

Here is a approach, whith a new sample A4 document with "hello world" in it.

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    //creating a sample Document
    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f);
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
    doc.Open();
    doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Chunk("hello world"));
    doc.Close();
    byte[] result = ms.ToArray();
}
```