# response.end() thread was being aborted exception is throw While generating pdf dynamically using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am generating pdf by itextsharp dynamically. But it throw exception 
 **thread was being aborted exception** at Response.End()

I tried to call the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest method instead of Response.End

It is avoid my exception but **popup is not coming for downloading pdf** 
and Popup for downloading pdf is working on localhost. but it is not working on online.

I tried to remove try-catch block. but still it is not working solution.

Here is my code

---

```
try
{
.
.    
    pdfDoc.Close(); 
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true; 
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=xyz.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    //Response.End() //HERE ERROR IS Show. Control goes to Catch block.
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Convert the PDF to a Byte Array and send it to the OutputStream `Response.OutputStream.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);`

Comment: I think that's what you want: http://alandennis.blogspot.fr/2005/07/streaming-pdf-using-itextsharp-and.html (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192384/itextsharp-how-to-convert-document-to-byte)

Comment: According to [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629), the behavior that `ThreadAbortException` occurs if you use `Response.End` is so by design.

Comment: I tried according to you posted blog link. Still Control is goes into Catch block. after Response.end() it Show response.end unable to evaluate
expression because the code is optimized Exception is show. and Session ll expired. @– VDWWD @ Kevin Gosse

Comment: According to [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response.end,-response.redirect,-or-server.transfer) - this Microsoft article. It is not helping to achieve my Output. @mkl

Comment: *It is not helping to achieve my Output* - At least it explains that the exception you observe ("HERE ERROR IS Show. Control goes to Catch block.") is thrown by `Response.End` by design. Thus, you obviously should not catch it but instead expect it. Furthermore, the exception is not related to iTextSharp as you appear to indicate in your question. All that been said I would propose you show more of your code, in particular the code in which you initialize or finalize the actual iTextSharp PDF generation. There is a smell to the code above that hints at other errors there.

Comment: yes.. I got your point @mkl. But Why my pdf is not downloading from server. It is working properly on localhost. But When i put same code on server The page loading appx 10-15 sec than Time is out and session is expired automatically. Thank you for replying me. :)

Comment: I doubt that difference can be analyzed based on the information you gave. Do you create very big documents? Or does the PDF generation take very long due to e.g. access of remote data sources? The former might result in weird situations if there is not enough memory, and the latter might make a difference if the remote data sources are more difficult / time-consuming to reach from the server.Etc...

Comment: Yes. @mkl. It is very big Document and totally generating dynamically. 16772 lines of code is genrating pdf Document. i had Optimized my Store procedure to. But it is does not make hug different.

Comment: Have you considered creating the document in a separate thread?

Comment: Yes I am doing r&d on that @mkl. If You have any source to do with thread please  Share it. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, I'd know how to do that in java but I've not yet done such things in .Net.

Comment: It is ok :) @mkl